# Animation for div when it enters the viewport horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm creating an infinite horizontal feed where I want to animate the element when it enters the viewport horizontally. I'm trying waypoint.js for this.

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhf95sLf/)

```
<div id="container">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Adding .show to div which will change opacity of div from 0 to 1.

```
$(function() {
$(".item").each(function(){
   $(this).waypoint(function() {
     $(this).addClass('show');
     }, {
       offset: '100%',
       horizontal: true
     });  
 });      
});
```

CSS

```
.item
{
width:500px;
height:250px;
background:red;
color:#fff;
display:inline-block;
opacity:.2;
}
.item.show
{
opacity:1;
}
```

But now the elements would not change their opacity from 0 to 1 when they enter the viewport horizontally. Any idea why? Sorry, I'm really new to javascript and waypoint.

Comment: what your actual problem..?

Comment: @AjayMakwana Sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: mean you want to make slider ,right??

Comment: please check the fiddle. The boxes need to appear with a fade in effect when you just scroll the page horizontally using the mouse.

Comment: make width:100% and offset: '50%' see whats happen

Answer (score 0):

The 100% width is incorrect; if you change it to 500px (the specified width of the individual items), it will work. This is non-optimal though (you will need to update both the JS and CSS whenever you change anything): a better approach would probably be to get the width of the items via JS, and use that value as the offset.

Percentage values passed to `offset` are percentages of the viewport, which I assume is not what you want here, rather the offset should be ~the width of each item. At the minute, any item even partially within the viewport is opaque, so you never see any change.

See http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the waypoint handler is not the element, it is the Waypoint instance. You want to use `$(this.element).addClass('show')`

Answer (score 0):

**[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaypancholi2626/Lcjvfy15/)**

problem on your code is that inside the `waypoint` callback function, `$(this)` refers to the Waypoint object, not the original `DOM` element. To fix this, you should store the reference to the original DOM element outside the waypoint callback

```js
$(function() {
    $(".item").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this); // Store the reference to the original DOM element

      $this.waypoint(function() {
        $this.addClass('show'); // Use the stored reference here
      }, {
        offset: '100%',
        horizontal: true
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
.item {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease; /* Add a transition for a smoother effect */
  }

  .item.show {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```